# Can't catch tab click event after dynamically created tabs

Tags: jquery

I have a function that creates a bunch of tabs based on returned ajax data, this function runs when a row has been changed from a grid, so when I click on a row it generates the tabs. 
However my tab click event isn't firing now and I am not sure why

The html is

```
<div id="AreaTabs">
<!-- New CM -->
<div id="DynamicTabsWrapper">
    <ul id="List" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
</div>
```

and the function that generates the tabs on the row click event of a grid is

```
function CreateTabs() {
    for (i = 0; i < junkData.length; i++) {

        $('#List').append("<li id='" + junkData[i].AreaID + "' class='nav-item not-active'><a class='nav-link' href='" + junkData[i].AreaName + "' data-toggle='tab' data-e='abc'>" + junkData[i].AreaName + "</a></li>");

        $("#List li").first().addClass("active").removeClass("not-active");

    }
}
```

and to get the tab click event is this

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('#List.nav-link li.active').removeClass("active");
    GetTarget(e);
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass("not-active");
});
```

If I run the CreateTabs function in the document.ready then I can catch the tab click events, but now I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is expected behavior; `.on()` attaches an event handler to the element(s) that match the selector - if your elements aren't part of the DOM when that script runs, they won't have said event attached to them.

This is easily supported though through the same `.on()` method; you just need to use delegation, meaning attaching your event handler to an element that *is* part of your page when your script runs. Within your handler you then pass the selector for the descendant elements that will be added to your page after the script runs. This is explained in detail in the jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

To apply this to your sample code would simply be:

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    $('#List.nav-link li.active').removeClass("active");
    GetTarget(e);
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass("not-active");
});
```

Of course you don't have to use `body`, but absent your source page HTML, that's the only delegate I could assuredly use. Assuming `#List` is part of your page when your script runs, you could also swap `body` for that.

Comment: I made the changes and everything is working, one issue that I have ran into is that if I only generate one tab, then I can't get the tab click event to work, any idea's

Comment: Insert a `console.log` statement in your click handler to see if it's actually running. Without your actual HTML & overall JS it's hard to know but the first thing your function does appears to be looking for another active tab & removing it as such. Maybe that fails when you have only one tab...? Once you find the root problem, you can likely handle for it with a ternary or if-else.

Comment: I think the issue was having the first tab set to active, because when I removed the active class from it i was able to catch the tab click event